# Can not see updated state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I have the following action:

```
export function loginUserRequest() {
  console.log('ACTION CALLED');
  return {
    type: LOGIN_USER_REQUEST,
  };
}
```

and this is the reducer:

```
export default function loginReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGIN_USER_REQUEST:
      console.log('REDUCER CALLED');
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isAuthenticated: true,
        isAuthenticating: true,
        statusText: null,
      });
    default:
      return initialState;
  }
}
```

Then, my component:

```
class Login extends React.Component {

  goHome = () => {
    browserHistory.push('/');
  }

  handleSubmit = (values) => {
    console.log(this.props.isAuthenticating);
    this.props.actions.loginUserRequest();
    console.log(this.props.isAuthenticating);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <LoginForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
    );
  }
}

Login.propTypes = {
  actions: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.func).isRequired,
  isAuthenticating: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  token: state.login.token,
  isAuthenticated: state.login.isAuthenticated,
  isAuthenticating: state.login.isAuthenticating,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  actions: bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

`LoginForm` is a `redux-form` component.

So, the expeted ouput from the `handleSubmit` function is:

```
false
ACTION CALLED
REDUCER CALLED
true
```

but it is giving me:

```
false
ACTION CALLED
REDUCER CALLED
false
```

But in the `redux dev tool` I can see the diff in `LOGIN_USER_REQUEST`:

[image]

Why I don't see it inside the `handleSubmit` function? Is it something related to `redux-form` library?

Extra info:

Added `shouldComponentUpdate` and `logger`

```
shouldComponentUpdate = (nextProps, nextState) => {
    console.log('Should component update called');
    if (this.props.isAuthenticating !== nextProps.isAuthenticating) {
      console.log('distntict');
      return true;
    }
    console.log('false');
    return false;
  }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try to add `shouldComponentUpdate` method in your component, and return true, if the props were not equal.

Comment: @DmitriyKovalenko look at my updated post. I also added a logger

Comment: Only one more variant, that i can imagine, is that you dont connect your component via redux `connect` and not create `mapStateToProps`, but it seems, that you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting such a result because of async nature of Javascript. So in your code

```
handleSubmit = (values) => {
    console.log(this.props.isAuthenticating);
    this.props.actions.loginUserRequest();
    console.log(this.props.isAuthenticating);
  }
```

First, you are printing the value of prop, and then the action gets called but before the action returns a response with the updated state, your third statement gets called to log the value and since the state is not yet updated you see the same result.

One approach will be have callbacks but that doesn't seem to be a requirement for your case. If your want to log the state then you can do so in `componentWillReceiveProps` function

like

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
     if(this.props.isAuthenicating != nextProps.isAuthenticating) {
          console.log(nextProps.isAuthenticating);
     }
}
```

I hope it helps